# Como criar gráficos usando séries temporais mostrando todos os meses no eixo x no R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gráfico, séries-temporais

Suponhamos que tenho a seguinte série temporal:

```
PREVISAO_VL_TR = ts(PREVISAO_VL_TR, start = c(2019,1), end = c(2019,12), frequency = 12 )
```

E que agora gostaria de criar um gráfico dessa série temporal:

```
plot(PREVISAO_VL_TR, col="red", lty = 2, type = "b",ylim = c(0,35000000),
     ylab = "Valor Transação", xlab = "Meses",main="Valor Transação")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que meu eixo x do gráfico, não corresponde exatamente com os meses da minha série temporal. Eu gostaria que ficasse com o ano/mês em cada ponto do gráfico.

Não sei se é possível fazer essa alteração, vi alguns artigos que fazia a modificação, mas não tive sucesso. Também tentei usar o `ggplot2`, mas não consegui aplicar com as séries temporais.

O que devo fazer para criar gráficos usando séries temporais mostrando os meses no eixo x no R?

Segue os dados para ajudar na resposta:

```
dput(PREVISAO_VL_TR)
structure(c(26784859.5861874, 27528503.7932623, 29404228.6092765, 
28924310.4063269, 28776524.1089006, 28258468.9552768, 24918740.8746702, 
27708496.9694671, 26311039.5724641, 25659967.9734825, 23610019.2328564, 
21111679.3716086, 23121492.473788), .Tsp = c(2019.08333333333, 
2020.08333333333, 12), class = "ts")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O pacote [ggfortify](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggfortify/index.html) adiciona ao ggplot a capacidade de reconhecer objetos da classe `ts`, entre outras. A detecção da escala pelo ggplot costuma ser boa (no caso, irá exibir meses e anos automaticamente), mas você pode usar `scale_date` para personalizar.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)

autoplot(PREVISAO_VL_TR) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%B/%Y", date_breaks = "2 months")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Consulte a [vinheta do pacote sobre séries temporais](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggfortify/vignettes/plot_ts.html) para ver mais opções.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta e pelo material Carlos.